# ui-router 0.2.8 , why the release dir is empty?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bower, angularjs-routing

If I run

```
bower  install angular-ui-router --save
```

the release dir (and there is no file named angular-ui-router.js in other dirs) is empty so I can't include
the module in my script :(

Do anyone know what the problem is ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### UPDATE

After a long wait version 0.2.9 is out and has a higher precedence, so now we can install it  implicitly:

```
bower install angular-ui-router
```

[image]

---

#### BEFORE 0.2.9...

This was a bug in `bower.json` ignore option. fixed with this [commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/ccdab193315f304eb3be5f5b97c47a926c79263e)

They made a new release: **0.2.8-bowratic-tedium**.

Unfortunately, according to semver (see below) version 0.2.8-XXXXX is considered lower than 0.2.8!

#### So we must specify the version explicitly (bower follows the semver specification):

```
bower install angular-ui-router#0.2.8-bowratic-tedium --save
```

#### From http://semver.org/:

> 11). Precedence refers to how versions are compared to each other when ordered.
>
> ....
>
> Example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0.